# Can log in with removed login

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, login, user-accounts, openid

I have two Stack Exchange OpenIDs (different emails). Both are logins for my Stack Exchange accounts. I do the following:

1. Remove one of the logins.
2. Log out
3. Log in to Stack Overflow with the removed login.
4. I get the create account page (as expected).
5. After confirming the new account, I'm logged in to my old account
6. Both logins are listed again under "My Logins"

So it is impossible to remove a login.

When replacing step 3. with "login to StackExchange.com with the removed login" I get the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" site. Afterwards the same behavior.

Comment: Are you logged out of both OpenId accounts?

Comment: Are you using the same email for both of the accounts?

Comment: @rene I think so. When opening https://openid.stackexchange.com/ I'm not logged in.

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, two diffrent Emails.

Comment: Weird, I assume the new account is created then gets auto merged with your old account. Maybe because you still have it associated in other sites? Try removing the login on all sites you have account in

Comment: @ShadowWizard Removing the login on one site, does remove it from all site. I checked.

Comment: Hmm... try step #3 in Private/Incognito mode - any luck?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Did not help. But I noticed a slightly different behavior when logging in to StackExchange instead of StackOverflow with the removed login. See my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else having this problem: My old email was still in my profile.
 Removing it solved the issue.

I would expect a warning somewhere. Getting the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" site is definitely not right.

Answer (score 5):

Simply removing the login from your My Logins section of your profile does not actually *delete* the OpenID account. It can still be used to login and create an account. In this case, since it was previously connected to your account, attempting to create a new account with it causes the credential to be automatically merged into your existing account, which also re-adds it under your My Logins area.

There is a further process you must complete in order to have the OpenID account completely removed (no longer usable at all). We've emailed you instructions for how to go about doing that.

Comment: So creating a new account using the same OpenID is not possible?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Under most circumstances, no. I'm sure there are ways around it, but I'm not aware of them.