# Delete Stack Exchange OpenID

Tags: support, stack-exchange-openid

[Since I cannot permanently remove a login from my Stack Exchange accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273722/can-login-with-removed-login), is there a way to delete the Stack Exchange OpenID?

Comment: Use the [contact us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form (linked in the footer) and ask for it to be removed.